# Capture onChange event from inputComponent passed to OutlinedInput, Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use OutlinedInput with KeyboardDatePicker, both from Material UI. I'm passing a DatePicker as input component to 'OutlinedInput' component of Material UI. I want to know how to get date from the inputComponent I'm passing.

With the following code I'm getting "_onChange is not a function" error.

```
    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        if (event.target.name === "deliveryDate") {
            temp.deliveryDate = event.target.value;
        }
    }


    function datepicker() {
        return <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
               <KeyboardDatePicker
                    name="deliveryDate"
                    format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                    value={projectDetails.deliveryDate}
                    onChange={props.handleInputChange} />  //not sure if this is how I should write it
               </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>;
    }


return(
    <OutlinedTextBox
          name="deliveryDate"
          id="deliveryDate"
          maxlength={20}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          inputComponent = {datepicker}   //passing the KeyboardDatePicker as input component
          inputLabel="Delivery Date" />
      )
```

Below is my OutlinedTextBox component. It returns

```
                    <OutlinedInput
                        name={props.name}
                        inputProps={{
                            maxLength: props.maxlength?props.maxlength:100,
                          }}
                        onChange={props.handleInputChange}
                        {...props}
                    />
```

How to capture onChange function of inputComponent attribute.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

From what you said in your comment, all you actually have to do then is edit your datepicker component. You dont need to pass in the value, onChange or name directly as those are already being passed in as props from when you use `inputComponent={datepicker}`. So all you need to do is declare the props and spread them all into the KeyboardDatePicker.

```js
const DatePicker = (props) => {
  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        format="MM/dd/yyyy"
        {...props}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
};
```

**Original Answer**.

You could just add the `inputVariant="outlined"`property to the KeyboardDatePicker as that will make it outlined. Then you dont actually need to use the OutlinedInput component at all.

```js
<KeyboardDatePicker
    name="deliveryDate"
    format="MM/dd/yyyy"
    value={projectDetails.deliveryDate}
    onChange={props.handleInputChange}
    inputVariant="outlined
/>
```

Comment: Yeah that's a workaround. But I need to follow some project guidelines and reuse the existing components. Didn't show the whole component but I have a customised reusable OutlinedInput component which I'm using for multiple other form elements too. Need an exact solution to my question please.

Comment: Just did an edit. Also for future questions, if you do have things like specific project guidelines and rules you have to follow, include them in the question

Comment: You should only be getting it from the first parameter because thats how material ui has created the components. If you have a look at the mui-pickers api for KeyboardDatePicker, you can see that the onChange event just returns the date. So there isn't any way to get e.target.value because that doesn't exist. Also you keep saying direct solution but you aren't specifying exactly what you want in the question all you are asking for is How to capture onChange function of inputComponent attribute. Maybe expand the question a bit more

https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker